# How to set gridlines for every value on the Y-axis in achartengine?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using **achartengine 1.0** and I am trying to set the gridlines for my **LineChart**.

The **Y-axis** has a min value of 1 and a max value of 7. I need the chart to display every step in this interval, so I added a label for 1, 2,3,... with

`addYTextLabel();`

Now I would like to display a gridline for every value on the **Y-axis**.

But when I add the grid for this axis, there are only 3 lins, at 2, 4 and 6.

How can I get the grid to show a line for all values?

best regards,
htz

Comment: problem solved... with setYLabels() you can set the number of displayed labels for the Y axis. With a displayed label, there comes a gridline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with `setYLabels()` you can set the number of displayed labels for the Y axis. With a displayed label, there comes a gridline.